# PXE-E53: No boot filename received when installing windows from USB

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, pxe

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I've downloaded Windows 10 and put the .iso file on a usb drive. I've updated my BIOS to UEFI and chose to boot from the USB. I'm getting the following error:

`PXE-E53: No boot filename received`

Most of the help that I've found while researching this is for when the error happens in existing windows systems, and seems to point to an issue with my USB drive, but I'm not clear what that issue is.

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: We regularly see questions in here about installing Windows, and people make this way harder than it needs to be. You do not need an .iso file. .iso files are for CDs. Download the media creation tool from Microsoft and it will make the bootable USB drive for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. When I search for microsoft media creation tool, it ends up having me download the iso file. Is there a different tool I should be using?

Comment: I found one here but its an exe, which I'm not able to run https://www.techspot.com/downloads/downloadnow/6734/?evp=3e01b158e760f60b81b3624ec2ee5c32&file=1

Comment: Are you trying this from Ubuntu or from Windows? It’s a Windows program, so you can’t create the bootable usb from Ubuntu. I’m not sure that your USB is the problem anyways. Typically PXE refers to network booting. So, I think your system is not trying to boot from USB at all. If it is, it’s failing. So, make sure you are actually selecting to boot from the USB, and if it fails you’ll need to revisit your process for creating a bootable USB. That’s why the Windows tool is convenient, it does it for you and works every time with a couple clicks.

Comment: I'm currently running ubuntu and creating the USB from ubuntu, and I'm trying to install windows 10 this way. I'll go back and again, I've been selecting to boot from the USB, so I'm not sure why it would be trying to boot from the network, that's part of my confusion.

Comment: I've verified that USB is booting first, im still seeing the PXE issue though

Comment: If your USB is not bootable it’s going to failover to other boot options. I’d have to say that’s what’s going on. PXE-E53 is definitely network booting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'll also look into using that media tool on a windows machine to create the usb when I get a chance.

Comment: Currently the only tool for Ubuntu that can reliably "burn" the new Microsoft ISOs is MKUSB, very easy to install and use: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: I've tried MKUSB but the result was throwing an error on boot. What ended up working in the end was making the usb with the media creation tool on a separate windows machine.